# Javascript get array by name of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a total of 5 arrays.
Name of the array will be selected by the user, based on the users selection we need to perform actions.

```
var p1s1 = ['5', '1', '6'];
var p1s2 = ['2', '4', '7'];
var p1s3 = ['9', '5', '2'];
var p1s4 = ['2', '5', '8'];
var p1s5 = ['7', '4', '2'];
```

when user selects a dropdown it will have value p1s3. So i need to pick this particular array and perform operations over this.
Could anyone please suggest in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: You can put them inside an object, and refer to them by key. Getting variables dynamically by name is a recipe for disaster, and not possible in JS anyway.

Comment: You need to have object which is a collection of `key=>value` pair. In your case key will the the name user selects and value will be the array. I hope this helps...

Comment: Please search before posting. This has been asked several dozen times before, the ground has been thoroughly covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use object instead:

```
var obj = {
  p1s1: ['5', '1', '6'],
  p1s2: ['2', '4', '7'],
  p1s3: ['9', '5', '2'],
  p1s4: ['2', '5', '8'],
  p1s5: ['7', '4', '2']
}
```

Then access array this way:

```
obj[selected_value_from_dropdown]
```

Comment: obj.p1s3, is also valid

Comment: @A.T. yes valid but the value is coming from somewhere else and is a variable so the answer is valid

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tackle the solution is having an object rather than multiple variables call it pickUpArray

```
var pickUpArray = {
  p1s1 : ['5', '1', '6'],
  p1s2 : ['2', '4', '7'],
  p1s3 : ['9', '5', '2'],
  p1s4 : ['2', '5', '8'],
  p1s5 : ['7', '4', '2']
};
```

Then in your logic say you have the value as `val` where val = as string `'p1s5'` or `'p1s2'` etc, which is being passed from the select dropdown. you can select `pickUpArray[val]`

If you dont have a choice to change this varables you can call `eval(val)` where val is as string `'p1s5'` or `'p1s2'` etc, which is being passed from the select dropdown but highly unadvisable.